# How to create a newcommand with knitr?

Tags: sweave, knitr

I am using `knitr` and I'd like to make some new commands to combine common tasks into one, e.g. `\newcommand{\numps}[1]{\numprint{\Sexpr{#1}}}` so that I can do something like `\numps{pi}`. I can't seem to get it to compile though. I'd get the following error:

`mwe.tex:7: Package numprint Error: empty argument.`

What can I fix this? Thanks.

An MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{numprint}
\newcommand{\numpS}[1]{\numprint{\Sexpr{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\numpS{pi}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Today, I had to define several `\newcommand`'s in order to avoid hard-coding calculated numbers in a verbatim LaTeX diagram coded using package `tikzcd`. This chunk

````
```{r results='asis'}
newcommand <- function(cmdname, ...){
  cat(paste("\\newcommand\\", cmdname, "{", ..., "}", sep=""))
}
newcommand("oracindi", round(mean(max.Pr), 3))
newcommand("pragindi", round(mean(max.Pr_14), 3))
# ...
```
````

allowed me to use commands `\oracindi`, `\pragindi`, ... in place of hard-coded numbers in the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because of the way that `knitr` (and Sweave) function.  `knitr` processes the document before TeX, and replaces the `\Sexpr{#1}` with whatever R will give for `#1`.  Given the error, it appears that the entire `\Sexpr{#1}` is replaced with nothing (empty argument).  So in the `knitr` output that LaTeX gets,

```
\newcommand{\numpS}[1]{\numprint{\Sexpr{#1}}}
```

has become something like

```
\newcommand{\numpS}[1]{\numprint{}}
```

which obviously won't work.

As a workaround, you might think about defining an R function that would wrap its argument in the LaTeX commands you want.  Something along the lines of `\Sexpr{numps(pi)}`.